# Fetch Hours from Created date

Tags: oracle

I'm just trying to fetch Hour of my table from created date in Oracle 12c Database but it is showing error **INVALID EXTRACT FIELD FOR EXTRACT FIELD**. kindly guide me to fetch hour of my date my code is here...

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT( HOUR FROM (TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE,'RRRR-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')) ) HOUR
FROM
  INVOICE_V;
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: @Strawberry it is oracle 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my Date is stored as **6/1/2020 4:04:50 PM** in this format and Extract function is not accept this function.

Do not store dates as strings.

But, since you have, convert it from a string to a date using `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(CREATED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') ) AS HOUR
FROM   INVOICE_V;
```

If, however, you meant that its just displaying in that format (and is actually a `DATE` data type) then `CAST` the date to a timestamp:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( CREATED_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) ) AS HOUR
FROM   INVOICE_V;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `date` column (or the-like), then:

```
select extract(hour from cast(created_date as timestamp)) as hr
from invoice_v
```

Alternatively:

```
select to_char(created_date, 'hh24') as hr
from invoice_v
```

The first expression returns an integer number, while the second produces a string.

Note that `hour` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for an identifier (here, you used it as a column alias). I changed that.

Comment: Same error because my Date is stored as ***6/1/2020 4:04:50 PM*** in this format and Extract function is not accept this function.

Answer (score 1):

An `hour` can not be used in the `EXTRACT` function.

The only way to extract hour is to use `TO_CHAR` or subtract it from `TRUNC` date as follows:

```
TO_CHAR(created_date,'HH24') -- OR 'HH' as per your requirement
-- OR
FLOOR(24*(created_date- TRUNC(created_date)))
```

Please note that Oracle does not store dates in any format. It has its own binary representation. What you see while selecting from the table is based on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter.

You can set it according to your requirement.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_dATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'; -- like this
```